# Arduino Sketch with multiple NeoPixels (function taking different NeoPixels)

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller

I'm building an equalizer for the arduino and therefore i'm coding in c and i have the following problem, which is surely easy to solve, but i'm not able to find the solution, since i did not code much with c by now.
So here is what i want to do:

```
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip1 = Adafruit_NeoPixel(21, LEFT_BAND_1, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
   ...
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip14 = Adafruit_NeoPixel(21, RIGHT_BAND_7, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

Adafruit_NeoPixel strips[14] = {strip1,strip2,strip3,strip4,strip5,strip6,strip7,strip8,strip9,strip10,strip11,strip12,strip13,strip14};
```

Now i have a function that takes the following arguments:

```
void set_band_ledx(Adafruit_NeoPixel stripx,uint32_t color, float value,float value_old) {...}
```

And i want to use the function like this:

```
  for(int i = 0;i<1;i++){
  set_band_ledx(strips[i],strip[i].Color(c1, c2, c3), value_l[i],value_l_old[i]);
  }
```

The function itself works, if i use it for only one LED strip,
i guess the problem is about pointers. the function does simply not work like this and i could not manage to get it working.
The whole prorgram works fine if I test this without the array of strips.

So, where and how do i need to use pointers?
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: *Arduino* is not *C*. You should qualify *does simply not work* in a little bit more detail: *what works? what doesn't? what did you try?* -- As it is, it is only possible to guess what could be wrong in your project. *The guard `i < 1` is in the buggy code or in the working one?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this

```
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip1 = Adafruit_NeoPixel(21, LEFT_BAND_1, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
   ...
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip14 = Adafruit_NeoPixel(21, RIGHT_BAND_7, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

Adafruit_NeoPixel strips[14] = {strip1,strip2,strip3,strip4,strip5,strip6,strip7,strip8,strip9,strip10,strip11,strip12,strip13,strip14};
```

You occupy the memory equivalent of `2 * 14 = 28` *Adafruit_NeoPixel* in memory, instead of the needed `14`.

This would be better:

```
Adafruit_NeoPixel strips[14] = {
    Adafruit_NeoPixel(21, LEFT_BAND_1, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
    ...
    Adafruit_NeoPixel(21, RIGHT_BAND_7, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800)
}
```

---

Instead of passing `stripx` by value

```
void set_band_ledx(Adafruit_NeoPixel stripx, uint32_t color, float value, float value_old) {...}
```

you should pass it by *reference*

```
void set_band_ledx(Adafruit_NeoPixel &stripx, uint32_t color, float value, float value_old) {...}
```

---

Also, there doesn't seem to be any reason for passing `uint32_t color` as a separate argument, since apparently it's stored within the `stripx` instance:

```
  set_band_ledx(strips[i],strip[i].Color(c1, c2, c3), value_l[i],value_l_old[i]);
```

*(though I might be wrong on this without seeing the rest of the code.)*

Comment: Thank you very much, i guess i will get more comfortable working with pointers when i do it more frequently again!